# unable to find Transaction Hash

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, ledger-nano-s, trezor

I did a transaction about 14 hrs ago to move some ETH from one hardware wallet to another using myEtherWallet.  I received the "Sorry, We are unable to locate the Transaction Hash" message.  The ETH is still showing in the sending wallet.

Is this transaction lost or will it eventually show up as 'pending'?   Should I wait?

Transaction  0x875dba05d7e75dcdbe5a2884f9a3a36492fe56403aeef6487c493d06d8c50ea0

Comment: Hi there. Where did you send the transaction from? If it was from an exchange, then you'll need to open support ticket.

Comment: I sent it from a trezor hardware wallet.

Comment: I noticed it still doesn't show up - what happened? Having a similar issue.